# How do I restart from the first prompt?

Tags: javascript

I want to set it up so when I answer with a yes/no or y/n it returns to the first prompt again or ends it.

(I can translate it if you need it)

```
  var G = prompt('Digite o valor da Gasolina')
console.log('Gasolina = R$' + G)
  var A = prompt('Digite o valor do Álcool')
console.log('Álcool = R$' + A)
  var R = A / G
console.log('O % de diferença é: ' + R)
  if (R < 0.7)
console.log('Álcool vale mais a pena')
  if (R > 0.7)
console.log('Gasolina vale mais a pena!')
  prompt('Deseja efetuar um novo cálculo?')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it all in a function and call it again if they enter `y`.

```js
function doThing() {
  var G = prompt('Digite o valor da Gasolina')
console.log('Gasolina = R$' + G)
  var A = prompt('Digite o valor do Álcool')
console.log('Álcool = R$' + A)
  var R = A / G
console.log('O % de diferença é: ' + R)
  if (R < 0.7)
console.log('Álcool vale mais a pena')
  if (R > 0.7)
console.log('Gasolina vale mais a pena!')
  // Only do first character in case they enter "yes" or "yea"
  if (prompt('Deseja efetuar um novo cálculo?')[0].toLowerCase() == 'y') {
    doThing();
  }
};
doThing();
```

Comment: Instead of `prompt` it is better to use [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm), so it would return boolean value by default and there would be no mismatch between expected and actual input